# Choose a certain digit of a number

Tags: python

Let's say I have a digit

```
num = 3456
```

I would like to chose the third digit of that number (5), and then multiply that 5 by three. How would I do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: No code posted no accurate description of problem, yet effectively helped. way to churn out a code writing service..good job guys! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say we have this integer:

```
num = 3457
```

To select specific numbers, let's first convert it to string.

```
num_str = str(num)
```

Now we can select the third character.

```
third_digit = num_str[2]
```

Before multiplying it, we have to convert it back to integer.

```
print(int(third_digit) * 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is pretty old, but you can select the 'tens' digit by using:

```
num = 3456
third_digit = num // 10 % 10
```

If you don't know how many digits the number has and you want the nth digit, you can create a function to select any digit:

```
import math
num = 3456
def KthDigit(n, k):
    no_of_digits = math.floor(math.log10(n))+1
    return num // 10**(no_of_digits-k) % 10
newnum = KthDigit(num, 3)
print(newnum*3)
```

num // 10**(no_of_digits-k) strips off the last digits, leaving the first k digits.
That mod 10 (%10) gives you the last digit, which is the kth digit.

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic solutions:

1. Change the number to a string.  Extract the digit you want.  Change that back to an integer.  Multiply by 3.
2. Integer-divide the number by a power of 10 to remove digits to the right of the one you want.  Get the 1's digit with **% 10**.  Multiply by 3.

Comment: I think he would like the 10's digit.

Comment: ... which he will have once he's done the previous step.